# how to get the length of a 2D array in c#? lenght and GetLength are not helping

Tags: c#, arrays

here is my code. i want to remove some elements from my 2D array. for that i have run a for loop. but don't know how to bound the loop because it keeps giving me error that "index was outside the bounds of array" (if i use Length / GetLength ).  :

```
  int len1 = tagged_data.GetLength(0);
  int len2 = tagged_data.GetLength(1);
  int len = len1 + len2;
  Console.WriteLine(len); 
  for (int i = 0; i <= len1;i++ )
   {

                    if (tagged_data[i, 1] != "'NN'")//|| tagged_data[i, 1] != "'NNS'"|| tagged_data[i, 1] != "'VBD'" || tagged_data[i, 1] != "'VBG'" || tagged_data[i, 1] != "'VB'" || tagged_data[i, 1] != "'VBZ'")
                    {
                        tagged_data[i, 1] = null;

                    }
                    else if (tagged_data[i, 1] != "'NNS'")
                    {
                        tagged_data[i, 1] = "";

                    }
                    else if (tagged_data[i, 1] != "'VBD'")
                    {
                        tagged_data[i, 1] = "";

                    }
                    else if (tagged_data[i, 1] != "'VBG'")
                    {
                        tagged_data[i, 1] = "";

                    }
                    else if (tagged_data[i, 1] != "'VBZ'")
                    {
                        tagged_data[i, 1] = "";

                    }
                    else if (tagged_data[i, 1] != "'VB'")
                    {
                        tagged_data[i, 1] = "";

                    }
                    else
                        Console.Write("nothing to eliminate");
                }
```

Comment: Eh, you probably mean `int len = len1 * len2;` (multiplication `*` instead of addition: `4x5` array has `20` items, not `9`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For loop should be

`for (int i = 0; i < len1;i++ )`

because length give total size and index start with zero. So last index will be total length - 1.

e.g.

`int[]  a = {1,2,3,4}` will have length 4 but index will be 3.

Answer (score 1):

Too many errors you have got:

- wrong *size*: `len = len1 * len2`: `*` instead of `+`; `7 x 3` array has `7 * 3 == 21` items
- wrong *indexing*: `for (int i = 0; i < len1; i++)`, not `i <= len1`.
- wrong `if` *logic*: your current implementation will set *all* `[i, 1]` items to `null`.

Sonething like this (eliminating tags):

```
String[,] tagged_data = ...

...   

Console.WriteLine(tagged_data.Length);

HashSet<String> tagsToRemove = new HashSet<String>() {
  "'NN'", "'NNS'", "'VBD'", "'VBG'", "'VBZ'", "'VB'",  
};

for (int i = 0; i < tagged_data.GetLength(0); ++i)
  if (tagsToRemove.Contains(tagged_data[i, 1]))
    tagged_data[i, 1] = null;
  else 
    Console.Write("nothing to eliminate");
```

In case you want to *preserve* the tags:

```
Console.WriteLine(tagged_data.Length);

HashSet<String> tagsToPreserve = new HashSet<String>() {
  "'NN'", "'NNS'", "'VBD'", "'VBG'", "'VBZ'", "'VB'",  
};

for (int i = 0; i < tagged_data.GetLength(0); ++i)
  if (!tagsToPreserve.Contains(tagged_data[i, 1]))
    tagged_data[i, 1] = null;
  else 
    Console.Write("nothing to eliminate");
```

Comment: Loads of Thanks sir for your help but what is wrong with my for loop? i couldn't get it. If that element is not what i want it to be, it would be replaced with null. so what is wrong???

Comment: @Rida Akhtar: so you want to set item to `null` unless it's in the `tagsToPreserve` (my second code sample). In this case you want to implement it explicitly `!(tagged_data[i, 1] == "'NNS'" && ... && tagged_data[i, 1] == "'VBZ'")`

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace
 `for (int i = 0; i <= len1;i++ )`
 with 
`for (int i = 0; i < len1; i++)`

The reason behind this is that the Length start counting from 1 until the total length, but the index of an array starts from 0, therefor you get this exception if you try to access the array[len1].

Answer (score 0):

Correct for loop should be:

`for(int i = 0; i < len1; i++)`

To iterate over an array you need to execute loop starting from 0 to (arrayLength - 1) because the array index starts from 0 and goes to (arrayLength - 1)

Consider this array:

`int a[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}; //Length: 5, Index range: 0 - 4`

In the above example the values are stored as:

- 1 at index 0
- 2 at index 1
- 3 at index 2
- 4 at index 3
- 5 at index 4

Thus, your loop will execute from 0 to 4 in this case which is 1 less than the length of array.